# A question on the order topology of $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$

Tags: general-topology

I was not able to ask a follow up question of the answer posted in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008798/a-question-on-semi-totally-continuous-function). I am confused with the order topology on the set $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$. I really dont know the purpose of the inclusion of the symbol $\infty$. Can someone help me clarify this thing? Thanks for any help.

Comment: One reason to study this space is that if $\{a_n\}$ is an infinite sequence of real numbers, then the limit of the sequence is equivalent to "extending" $\{a_n\}$ to infinity. That is, if $a:\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$, then finding a limit of $a(n)$ is equivalent to finding an value $a(\infty)$ to make $a$ continuous on all of $X$. (You can replace $\mathbb R$ by any nice topological space, and define limits of sequences there.)

Comment: @Thomas Andrews. Thanks.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \infty \}$ denotes the set consisting of the natural numbers together with one additional element, and we use $\infty$ to name that additional element. The name $\infty$ implicitly implies that we intend to extend the usual ordering so that $\infty$ is larger than the other elements. (if this is actually an answer, let me know and I'll move it out of the comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $\infty$ denotes a point not in $\Bbb N$ that you are to think of as being bigger than each $n\in\Bbb N$. In other words, the order on $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ looks like this:

$$0\quad1\quad2\quad3\quad4\quad5\quad\ldots\quad\infty$$

In this topology the subset $\Bbb N$ is an open subset with the discrete topology, so every subset of $\Bbb N$ is open. The point $\infty$ is a limit point of the set $\Bbb N$: the open nbhds of $\infty$ are the sets $U\subseteq\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$ such that $\infty\in U$ and $\Bbb N\setminus U$ is finite: they are the sets that contain the point $\infty$ and all but finitely many other points of the space.

This space is homeomorphic to the space $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ with the usual topology inherited from the real line: $0$ in this space corresponds to $\infty$ in the first space, and $\frac1n$ in this space corresponds to $n-1$ in the first space, as shown below.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&2&3&4&5&\ldots&\infty\\
1&\frac12&\frac13&\frac14&\frac15&\frac16&\ldots&0
\end{array}$$

Comment: @user135395: You’re very welcome.